# Blank screen with blinking cursor after running xdiagnose

Tags: drivers, login, screen, lightdm, 15.04

I have had this problem twice in a row trying to follow these instructions:

[Solution for low screen resolution in Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu](http://forum.linuxbsdos.com/topic/201/solution-for-low-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-14-10-and-virtualbox)

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04, and had everything running okay since the last time this happened months ago. My computer specs are:

Lenovo ThinkCentre SFF
A4-Series APU Processor Speed 3.40 GHz Processor Model A4-5300
AMD Radeon HD 7480D IGP
8GB RAM
OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Okay, so first of all, why I am repeating this, is because I want to install a discrete graphics card. Before doing so, I wanted to get the graphics drivers back to the standard settings. I had the proprietary drivers installed for the GPU that is integrated to the motherboard. So I used the additional driver application to revert back to the X drivers. Rebooted, the result was what the above link describes, built in display, bad resolution. The link asks to start up xdiagnose and check the all of the first three options, apply, and then reboot. This loads up what I assume are a lot of log informative things, but the result like last time lead me to the blank screen with blinking cursor. Tried to from ALT+F1 terminal to manually start lightdm, which lead to a critical error of some sort, (lightdm:1297):CRITICAL Session_set_login1_Session_ ... !Null= FAILED ...
Ths seems like it might have a simple solution to it, but it evades me.

Tried reinstalling lightdm.
Tried reinstalling xserver-xorg.
tried removing and reinstalling xdiagnose, but it still seems to be running when I reboot and leads to the same result.
Tried purging any fglrx drivers, whcih it found none, and then reinstalling xserver-org.

I'm confused, because I didn't think xdiagnose would lead to this issue, but seems like whenever I try t use it, it causes this problem. Anyone have a clue as to what I am doing to cause this result? Maybe how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Allright, after a while of pulling my hair out, I went as far as removing the configuration files for gnome by this command

rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity

This resulted I think in only putting my unity desktop back to its default setting, because what I did next solve my issue, and unity was reset to defaults, not sure which one did what, but just removing xdiagnose with:

sudo apt-get remove xdiagnose

didnt work, the command that removed all configurations for xdiagnose that did work was this:

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xdiagnose

Not sure what the big difference was, but it removed a ton more stuff, and even some sort of fglrx stuff that was still lingering I guess. the result is that Unity loaded up after restart and all applications and such were intact, just that I was at the default unity display liek fresh isntall because I removed those gnome config files I think. The problem though, was that it still was doing the debug bootup, doing all the green ok's and stuff when restartin gthe machine, so to fix that, I reinstalled xdiagnose:

sudo apt-get install xdiagnose

loaded it up, and to my surprise, all the features were checked, so I unchecked the top two options, and then the machine restarted as normal, using the xserver, and all is well in the world once again. Hope that helps someone in this mess.