# Ubuntu stuck on black screen with blinking underscore after using xdiagnose

Tags: boot, xorg, display

I was having issues with my resolution, and after some googling, decided to use xdiagnose, I selected all three debug options, hit start and then restarted my computer. Now when I try to boot back into Ubuntu, it opens a terminal (that I can't type in) that shows a bunch of checks saying stuff about it booting up, then it directs me to a black screen with blinking underscore, and won't finish booting. I've sat on the screen for 15 minutes or so and still nothing happens.

Comment: Can you use Ctrl+Alt+F2 or Ctrl+Alt+F3? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem (14.04 LTS). Neither Ctrl+Alt+F2 or Ctrl+Alt+F3 do anything, the system just sits there on a black screen with a blinking cursor.
Originally I was using the fglrx drivers so that certain games would function under wine. However this made graphics performance untenable in other native games, so I reverted back to the X drivers. That's when it started not being able to detect my correct screen resolution, and from there my story matches OP.

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this issue on my computer, following the solution [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630084/blank-screen-with-blinking-cursor-after-running-xdiagnose)

Specifically, these steps were performed:

1. Restart your machine holding `shift`, and boot into recovery mode.
2. Open a `root` command prompt, and mount your system drive in `rw` using the command `mount -o remount,rw /`.
3. Uninstall `xdiagnose` completely by entering `apt-get purge --auto-remove xdiagnose`.
4. Restart your system by entering `shutdown -r 0`. The system should boot normally, although mine still showed the diagnostic information.
5. Log in and reinstall `xdiagnose` by entering `sudo apt-get install xdiagnose` in a terminal window.
6. Once installed, open `xdiagnose` and **disable** the diagnostic options.